# user_id:nil when a comment is posted to Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

My app is giving me an error when I try to view show page. Here is the error:

```
2014-04-23T03:26:23.544575+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method     `image' for nil:NilClass):
2014-04-23T03:26:23.544575+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <%= div_for(comment) do %>
2014-04-23T03:26:23.544575+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:     <%= h(comment.body) %>
2014-04-23T03:26:23.544575+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:     <p class="comments">
2014-04-23T03:26:23.544575+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:         <strong>Posted <%=     time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago by <%= image_tag comment.user.image, class:     "smallpic_comment" %><%= comment.user.name %></strong></br>
2014-04-23T03:26:23.544575+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     </p>
2014-04-23T03:26:23.544575+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:     <% if user_signed_in? %>
2014-04-23T03:26:23.544575+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:         <% if current_user == comment.user || current_user.admin? %>
```

Whats happening is that when the app tries to display the show view, it looks at a section I display at the bottom for comments. For some reason, the comments are now posting with user_id:nil. It works fine locally. Here's my comment controller:

```
def create
@pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
@comment = @pin.comments.create(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user

MyMailer.comment_email(@pin.user).deliver

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
    format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :body, :pin_id, :author
 belongs_to :pin
 belongs_to :user
end
```

I assume it has some issue all of a sudden with @comment.user = current_user.

I appreciate any help, and let me know if you need more info. Here is the live site: www.thetens.us and github: https://github.com/Tambe257/thetens

Comment: Are your sure that current_user is not nil and user_signed_in? I suppose that you're using devise gem. Do you have any before_filer to authorize user?

Comment: @AntonGrigoryev I'm sure the current_user is ok, because I am able to add the actual album review. (this is a music review site) The app recognizes me when I add a review. I'll add the site url above.

Comment: Could you show Comment model?

Comment: @AntonGrigoryev Sure - See above. The reviews are called pins. Each comment belongs to a user and to a pin. When you look at my show page for the review (pin) you can see all of the comments below it. Again, this works fine locally, so its a Heroku DB issue. It just started a few days ago.

Comment: How does 'comment' get the value of '@comment' in your view?

Comment: My pin show page renders :partial => @pin.comments The partial is the "div_for(comment) do" part of the error that you see above. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Fred Do you have a suggestion of where to look next? Again, I'm not getting a current_user error, but it's not capturing the user_id when I post a comment. It works locally, and this just happened 4-5 days ago, even though I haven't made any changes to the site for 2 weeks. I've ran Heroku restart a few times, but that hasn't helped either.

Comment: How about adding a validation for Comment? I'd suggest using `validates_presence_of :user` first. Using `validates_associated :user` would make sure the User record is itself valid and in the db. There is a validates_existence gem, but I'm not certain what it does in Rails 4.

Comment: @Fred I am already authenticating the user in the controller. before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show] You're saying to try the validation in the model? I'll try it in a little while and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Fred I added the validates_presence_of :user and I still get an error, but now the error occurs before the comment is created, since the app tries to validate the user, but sees that it is nil. I went into the heroku console and deleted out the 5 comments that have been posted with no user_id, so I can at least see the show view now that no comments exist without ids. I still haven't figured out the issue unfortunately.

Comment: At least you know for sure that the problem is with `current_user`; what is in the session cookie?

Comment: @Fred I'll have to figure out how to check that. I haven't worked with that before. I also have a blog that is in the app and has it's own commenting framework that is totally separate from the other comments and the same thing happens when I comment there. It's obviously something that's changed on Heroku's end. (or all pg databases)

Comment: @Fred ok, I narrowed it down further. The problem is that I use gmail for my mailer smtp service. I had to change my password, and even though I updated it in my app, its causing an error. I took the mailer out for now and it works fine. I'll close this question and probably post a new one about why the password isn't working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mailer information has changed and when teh app tries to email, it can't send. Because the controller tries to execute the email when it saves the post, it's corrupting the file that it's saving.

I commented out the mailer temporarily until I fix that issue and it works fine now.

```
def create
@pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
@comment = @pin.comments.create(params[:comment])
@comment.user = current_user

#MyMailer.comment_email(@pin.user).deliver

respond_to do |format|
  if @comment.save
   format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
   format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created, location: @comment }
  else
 format.html { render action: "new" }
 format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
 end
end
end
```